# How do i check for a 302 response? WebRequest

Tags: .net, httpresponse, http-status-code-302

Using `WebRequest` I want to know if I get a

> "302 Moved Temporarily"

response instead of automatically get the new url.

Comment: Actually tags say everything about code.

Comment: They didn't before Aaron. jimyi retagged it.

Comment: whoops, i assume if you wouldnt know how to do it with WebRequest if you dont know what WebRequest is. .NET is a better tag, oops.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to detect a redirect response, instead of following it automatically create the `WebRequest` and set the `AllowAutoRedirect` property to `false`:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(someUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect || 
    response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently)
{
    // Do something here...
    string newUrl = response.Headers["Location"];
}
```

Comment: Haven't verified this myself, but I just found something saying: "If the HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect property is false, HttpStatusCode.Found will cause an exception to be thrown." Source: http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System.Net/types/HttpStatusCode.htm

Comment: @Nathan: I don't really see how, since HttpStatusCode is an enum. The linked documentation (needs to end in '.html' BTW) appears to be out of date; that sentence was probably a cut-and-paste bug.

Comment: BTW, you can also use HttpStatusCode.Redirect (another alias for 302), which is a bit more obvious.

Comment: amended the alias and added 301 as well

Comment: Another tweak; can use `response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.Location]` in your "do something" example as well (analogous to the status code constants).

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
HttpWebResponse response;
int code = (int) response.StatusCode;
```

The code should be

```
HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect
```

Comment: HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect is a 307. http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System.Net/types/HttpStatusCode.html#TemporaryRedirect

Comment: I can now see the reponse code, but it still redirects and gives me 'OK'

Comment: @Nathan Taylor: I copy/pasted what CURL gave me using curl -I "url"

Answer (score 1):

VB Net Code

```vb
Function GetRealUrl(someUrl As String) As String
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(someUrl), HttpWebRequest)
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = False
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Redirect OrElse response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently Then
            ' Do something...
            Dim newUrl As String = response.Headers("Location")
            getrealurl = newUrl
        Else
            getrealurl = someUrl
        End If
End Function
```