# C# WebRequest with php redirecting page

Tags: c#, php, url, redirect, webrequest

I am messing around trying to write a small web crawler.  I parse out a url from some html and sometimes I get a php redirect page.  I am looking for a way to get the uri of the redirected page.

I am trying to use System.Net.WebRequest to get a a stream using code like this

```
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(link);
        Stream s = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader st =  new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(link).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

The problem is that the link is a PHP redirect, so the stream is always null.  How would I get the URI to the page the php is redirecting?

Comment: Isnt it returning a HTTP 302? if so, there should be a response header indicating the new location. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391373/how-do-i-check-for-a-302-response-webrequest for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    reg.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    StreamReader _st = new StreamReader(_req.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(req.CharacterSet));
```

the AllowAutoRedirect will automatically take you to the new URI; if that is you're desired effect. The AutomaticDecompression will auto decompress compressed responses. Also you should be executing the get response stream part in a try catch block. I my exp it throws alot of WebExceptions.

Since you're experimenting with this technology make sure you read the data with the correct encoding. If you attempt to get data from a japanese site without using Unicode then the data will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Location" header from the response - it should contain the new URL.