# How to get website redirection target url (end-user-link)

Tags: c#, .net, html, redirect, http-redirect

I have a URL that redirects me to another website. I would like to get the target url from the original one in C#. Is there any way to follow these redirections?

Comment: You have a URL, and what are you doing with it? Using WebRequest?

Comment: I just need the "end-user-link". I tried to load it the webbrowser control, but when I get the location of the current page, it only shows the first url, not the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the HttpWebRequest class

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(someUrl);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found) // Found == 302
{
    // Do something...
    string newUrl = response.Headers["Location"];
}
```

Also, you can follow redirections automatically by setting:

```
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4; //number of redirections allowed
```

Related: [How do i check for a 302 response? WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391373/how-do-i-check-for-a-302-response-webrequest)

Comment: response.ResponseUri.OriginalString get me what I need.

Comment: Minor nit: I prefer to cast to `(HttpWebRequest)` and `(HttpWebResponse)`, since if the objects were somehow not the correct type, the `as` would return null and you'd get a `NullReferenceException` on the _next_ line. Better to get an `InvalidCastException` right away, on the line containing the problem.